# add item to a local json file using javascript object / java code

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I have a locally stored json file as c:\path\jsontext.json.
I have a jsp page and .js file,
In my .js file I have a javascript object, the data of this javascript object is in json format and i would like to append it to the jsontext.json file

But can figure out a way to do this.

Here is my jsontext.json

```
[
    {
        "Identifier": "1",
        "Label": "pratik",
        "Categories": "Standard",
        "UpdatedBy": "lno",
        "UpdatedAt": "01-02-2013"

    },
    {
        "Identifier": "2",
        "Label": "2013",
        "Categories": "Standard",
        "UpdatedBy": "lno",
        "UpdatedAt": "01-02-2013"
    }
]
```

supposing in my .js file i have a javascript object

```
var JSObject=("[{" +'"example1"'+"},"+ "{" + '"example2"' + "}]");
```

I want to append this data in my jsontext.json file,

how should I go about it.

I looked at some resources and found that I would require a server side programming language to get this done.

If I try doing this in a java code, then the code is easy to write. The only problem then is the java method will be execute first and then the .js file.

If there is a way - a clickevent on the .js file which can call the java method then it would also work for me.

I have this java code.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class JsonSimpleExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject JSONObject = new JSONObject();


    try {

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\jsontext.json");
        file.write(JSONObject.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print(JSONObject);

     }

}
```

Where should I include this java code in order to write the item into jsontext.json file.?
and.
IS there are method in Jquery for this??

Comment: `"[{" +'"example1"'+"},"+ "{" + '"example2"' + "}]"` wont give you json.

Comment: thats written just to explain my question. I know thats not the actual json.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get access to local file system from browser you might want to check [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

You cannot simply access clients computer from jQuery/JavaScript. User will need to permission that as well.